# Reading paged datagrids in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, datagrid

I keep getting this exception in Selenium ...

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document   (Session
>   info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550
>   (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64)'

This is insanely frustrating and I can't understand why I get the exception thrown in the return statement inside the BuildOrg method below.

Here's the code that triggers the problem ...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lastPage; i++)
{
    orgs.AddRange( 
        browser
            .FindElement(By.Id("all_organizations"))
            .FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"))
            .FindElements(By.TagName("tr"))
            .Select(e => BuildOrg(e))
    );

    browser
        .FindElement(By.Id("all_organizations_next"))
        .FindElement(By.TagName("a"))
        .Click();
}

 .....


Organisation BuildOrg(IWebElement orgElement)
{
    var cells = orgElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    var avatarUrl = cells[0].FindElement(By.TagName("img")).GetAttribute("src");
    var c = DateTimeOffset.Parse(cells[2].Text);
    return new Organisation
    {
        Id = int.Parse(avatarUrl.Split('_')[1].Split('/')[0]),
        Avatar = avatarUrl,
        Name = cells[1].Text,
        Link = cells[1].FindElement(By.TagName("a")).GetAttribute("href"),
        CreatedOn = c
    };
}
```

Can any lend any light on this?

Comment: try add sleep 10 seconds after click "all_organizations_next", if work, change static sleep to wait().   you need to wait the table loading complete before you try to interacte with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the row is probably being updated between two `.FindElement(s)`. Web elements are no longer usable if the page was updated or if the DOM element was replaced.

It's probably because the second iteration following the `.Click` starts even though the rows are not yet refreshed.

To overcome this issue, try to use a single `.FindElement(s)` and wait for one element to become stale after the `Click`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lastPage; i++)
{
    var rows = browser
      .FindElements(By.CssSelector("#all_organizations tbody tr"));

    orgs.AddRange(rows.Select(e => BuildOrg(e)));

    var link = browser
      .FindElement(By.CssSelector("a"))

    link.Click();

    new WebDriverWait(browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
      .Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(rows[0]));
}
```

Comment: Yeh I suspected something like that but didn't know how to stop it from happening, where is ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf defined? for me i'm getting an intellisense error saying it's not defined. Also I assume the actual value is a Func<IWebDriver, T> as that's what .Until() expects

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm. You could also craft your own predicate to wait at the beginning of the loop for the first row to be different from a previous cached one. Something like `.Until(_ => (rows=_.FindElements(...)).Length > 0 && !rows[0].Equals(cachedRow))`.

Comment: Hmmm, that triggers a OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException after the timespan (i set this to 30 seconds to be sure), the page clearly loaded in under a second then just sat there. Really not impressed with selenium right now!

Comment: You need to translate/code the behavior of a real user. There's no way the driver can know that the click is supposed to update the rows. If it wasn't for this error you would probably miss some values and end-up with some duplicates. So you should first figure-out how a user knows that the records have been updated and then wait for this state in your code.

Comment: I don't understand that ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(rows[0]) the xml doc on the method states "waits until the element is not attached to a doc", but surely my original problem was that the element was not attached to a doc and it implied that it should have been. Selenium is not intuitive to use at all. and no amount of introducing delays in the code seems to resolve the issue ... if I hard code a 10 second delay when the browser reports the page is fully loaded in under a second both on load and after the clicks it still complains.

Comment: It's hard to say without a reproducible example and without knowing the line throwing the error. From what you are describing, the click triggers an update of the rows which is not executed immediately since it has to wait for a response from the server to get the data. So one way to synchronize your script is to either wait for a previous row to be removed with `StalenessOf` or to wait for the first row to be different from the one of the previous iteration. That is, assuming the page is replacing the `<tr>` rows with new ones and not reusing them.

Comment: Try to wait with `StalenessOf` on the element throwing the error: `#all_organizations tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) a` or `#all_organizations tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) img`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155400/discussion-between-war-and-florent-b).

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReferenceException usually dealt with refresh of the entire DOM or only the component which is changed.

I am not able to understand the flow between for loop and buildOrg method that is returning Organization. Assuming the exception happening in one of the findElements method in buildOrg method:

```
try { 
  // do action that refresh DOM element
  // add wait condition if required 
  var cells = orgElement.findElements(By.TagName("td"));
} catch(StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
  // do action that refresh DOM element
  // add wait condition if required 
  var cells = orgElement.findElements(By.TagName("td"));
}
```

You may need to re-design your code in order to accommodate the above mentioned hack. Hopefully it helps!!!

Comment: It's considered bad practice to do flow control in an application with exception handling. If the Selenium API relies on this as "the standard" I would be very surprised and seriously considering ditching it for something else.

Comment: Agreed @War, but this is a hack to meet deadlines and save ourselves from frustration.

Comment: :( shame it won't work though ... (i actually did try this at one point)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that no amount of using Seleniums tools to "wait" click events results in the expected behaviour so I simply gave up and put in a "configurable delay" that I just pull from config to handle this.

To my mind Selenium is buggy as hell and simple things like browsing a to a url, clicking some buttons then browsing to another url and repeating the process often results in unexpected exceptions (like a socket exception because it crashed the browser instance) for seemingly no reason.

I would highly recommend that anyone with a Selenium issue simply go find another solution but if that fails do what I did ...

```
DoSeleniumStuff();
Thread.Sleep(configuredDelay);
DoSeleniumStuff();
```

It's ugly but it solves the problem for me.
I guess I can always thread multiple instances and do pieces on each thread to speed things up but that's ugly as hell too.

I also found the edge driver to be a ton more reliable than the chrome one.